# Versioning of npm dependencies with standard gitflow

Tags: node.js, git, npm, version-control, git-flow

I am following standard gitflow, and I have different environments for testing the dev builds, and release builds. master goes to production.

I also have my JS app divided into multiple private npm modules which goes into private npm repository.

#### Q1

Is there any way I can version my npm packages, against the branches they are built on in a standard way?

What I have tried is, I have `prerelease` `pre-ids` added to the versions. like
`1.0.0-rc.0 //for master`
`1.0.0-beta.0 //for release`
`1.0.0-alpha.0 //for dev`

But if I create a feature branch from master, it contains the master's version. When I try to raise a PR from it to dev, then it shows conflict, since dev has `-alpha.x` in its version. To resolve the conflict, I'll have to consume the target branch's versioning. Same issue when it goes for merging on release branch too.

And when it comes to merging to master, the release version (one with `-beta.0`) completely replaces the master.
So it becomes like this: on master,

```
| It was        | After Merge   | After version bump  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -------------------:|
| 1.0.0-rc.0    | 1.0.0-beta.0  | 1.0.0-rc.0          |
```

Ideally after the version bump i would have wanted it to be 1.0.0-rc.1

Is it possible to keep package JSONs out of versioning.

#### Q2

How do I control the versioning in the package JSON of the application where these NPM modules are consumed? It too is on *gitflow* and feature branching model, and I would want that the App, when it is building on *dev* branch, it builds with artifacts that are published from their respective *dev* branches.

Honestly, I might be misusing gitflow too, but as of now, too confused to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ignoring `package.json` file out of version control does can solve the problem in Q1. And what do you mean version package json comsumed with npm mopdeules in Q2?

Comment: ignoring `package.json` does not help in Q1. That means the version bump that happens on build machine will never get pushed to the repository, since `package.json` is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved it is, 

`//${buildNumber} and ${branch} are available as env variables in the build agent(at least available in jenkins/bamboo)
tagversion="1.0.0-${branch}.${buildNumber}" 
echo $tagversion
npm version $tagversion`

so my builds are created and published as

`1.0.0-master.1 //for master
1.0.0-release.1 //for release
1.0.0-dev.1 //for dev`

Answer (score 1):

You can user merge strategy as `ours` for `package.json` file in all branches. Details steps as below:

1. **Configure merge.ours.driver as true**

   ```
   git config --global merge.ours.driver true
   ```
2. **Add .gitattributes file on each branch**

   Add `.gitattributes` file with below content on each branch as below:

   ```
   echo 'package.json merge=ours' >> .gitattributes
   ```

   More details, you can refer last part (Merge Strategies) in [Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

Until now, for most situations, `package.json` file won't be overwritten during merge.

**Note:** `pakage.json` file will be overwritten for recursive merge. When merging changes from `branch1` to `branch2`, if the file `package.json` is only changed on `branch1`, the merge commit will keep the `package.json` file with the version from `branch1` by recursive merge strategy.

Such as on `master` branch, the version `1.0.0-rc.0` has not changed; while on `release` branch, the version has changes to `1.0.0-beta.0`. When merging changes from `release` branch into `master` branch, the version will be `1.0.0-beta.0` (as you mentioned).

So **for recursive merge situation, you need to manually change the `package.json` file version after merging**:

```
# On the merged branch, as master in above example
git checkout head~ -- package.json
git commit -m 'use the original package.json after recursive merge'
```